# email application help. Send email to made up email address which is redirected to real email

Tags: php, email, redirect

I'm wondering how i would go about making the following application:

- a user signs up, say with the username "johny-jones".
- Lets say for example that my domain is www.example.com
- if anyone emails johny-jones@example.com this email is redirected to johny-jones REAL email address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest option is to tell your smtp server to forward all ingoing mails to an external program (your php script). For example, for qmail this will be like `| php myphpscript.php` in `.qmail` file. Your script will read email from stdin and resend it to the real address.

Answer (score 0):

You're basically describing a [mail transfer agent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mail_transfer_agent) AKA mail server. So all you need to do is a server to run it on, the required MX DNS records, and an API that allows you to configure forward addresses. Look through the documentation of the servers
 [listed here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_mail_servers) to see which ones offer the latter.

Answer (score 0):

Just pipe all orphan email (specific to that domain) to ur PHP script and use something like this to extract the email content:

```
$fd = fopen("php://stdin", "r");
$email = "";
while (!feof($fd)) {
    $email .= fread($fd, 1024);
}
fclose($fd);
```

then extract the "to" field and if it belongs to a user .. forward the email to him.If you have cPanel .. this is even easier. goto mail > default address > set default address and instead of putting an email address there put something like this 
`"|php -q /home/whatever/public_html/pipe.php"` .. ofcourse without the quotes